# bsub and Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm running matlab jobs on a remote server. The documentation says to run 'script.m', use the following command:

```
bsub -o script.out -R "rusage[matlab=1:duration=1]" matlab -nodisplay script
```

This doesn't seem to do much (or anything).

However,

```
bsub -o script.out -R "rusage[matlab=1:duration=1]" matlab -nodisplay -r "script"
```

works though. Any idea why the -r and quotation marks were omitted in the documentation? Was this simply a mistake, or am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: You may want to report this to MathWorks as a documentation error.

Answer (score 0):

That looks just plain wrong to me, MATLAB has always needed the -r option to run a script.